# Tool/library to generate a report from multiple SQL query output?

Tags: database, reporting

I'm looking to generate a report where the data is from multiple SQL queries.  Some queries will have several columns/rows as output and I would like some control over what goes where.

Data is in a mySQL database.  Formatted text or CSV would be fine as output.  Would like to be able to automate this report.

Does anyone have recommendations on tools/libraries to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pretty much any reporting system. [Windward Reports](https://www.windwardstudios.com/) or Crystal Reports for paid. Jasper or Pentaho for free. (SSRS is out because you're on MySQL.) You can find a pretty good list at [Reporting Software](http://www.reportingsoftware.info/). The giant question you face is ease of use vs price.

If you're willing to pay for a commercial system, please take a look at Windward (disclaimer, I'm the CTO there). With Windward you design the report is Excel (best for your use), Word, or PowerPoint. So design & layout are a breeze. And yes, you can get output to XLSX, CSV, or pretty much anything else.